# Using element function within resource block

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-vpc, hcl

I am using `aws vpc module` and defined below variables.
I am trying to understand use of `element` and why the `cidr_block` is calculated as below:

```
element(concat(var.public_cidr_blocks, [""]), count.index)
```

Below are the `variable` and `resource block.`

```
variable "public_cidr_blocks" {
  type = list(string)
  default = [
    "182.10.10.0/24",
    "182.10.20.0/24"
  ]
}


variable "availability_zones" {
  type = list(string)
  default = [
    "us-east-2a",
    "us-east-2b"
  ]
}

resource "aws_subnet" "aws_public_subnets" {
  vpc_id                  = aws_vpc.myvpc.id
  cidr_block              = element(concat(var.public_cidr_blocks, [""]), count.index)
  availability_zone       = element(var.availability_zones, count.index)
  map_public_ip_on_launch = true
  count                   = length(var.public_cidr_blocks)
}
```

My question is why `[""]` has to be `concated here` in the `elements function.`

Comment: What's the issue?

Comment: My question is why `[""]` has to be `concated here` in the `elements function.`

Comment: It doesn't have to be used at all. Are there any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
element(concat(var.public_cidr_blocks, [""]), count.index)
```

What this line does, it makes sure that there is at least one element in the list, no matter what is the input for `public_cidr_blocks`.

The reason for this, I think, is an older issue from Terraform. I assume your module is based on the [`terraform-aws-modules`](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-vpc) implementation. In an older version of Terraform and/or terraform-provider-aws, there was with this error with detecting the type for elements in a list:

```
"var.public_subnets" does not have any elements so cannot determine type
```

To have a workaround for this, the fix was to add at list one element to the list which had the type of string. See this pull request: https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-vpc/issues/177

With newer versions of Terraform this issue was fixed. That line does not make much sense anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the details. I have downloaded the latest version of `aws-module` and even in that implementation they have added this line.

Comment: can you please help with 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76743950/how-to-modify-availability-zone-when-subnets-is-greater-than-availability-zone