# How to modify "availability_zone" when subnets is greater than availability zones?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-vpc, terraform0.12+

I have `aws_subnet` resource which looks as below:

```
resource "aws_subnet" "public_subnets" {
  cidr_block              = element(concat(var.psubnets, [""]), count.index)
  availability_zone       = element(var.azs, count.index)
  count                   = length(var.psubnets)
}
```

Here, how to update `availability_zone = element(var.azs, count.index)` to account for the situation when

```
len.subnets > len.azs
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [modulus operator](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/operators#-1) should help you account for this:

```
element(var.azs, count.index % len(var.azs))
```

For example if the `len(var.azs)` value is `3`, and you had `7` subnets, you would get the following:

| count.index | len(var.azs) | count.index % len(var.azs) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 3 | 0 |
| 1 | 3 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 | 0 |
| 4 | 3 | 1 |
| 5 | 3 | 2 |
| 6 | 3 | 0 |